# Memset not working in outside function

Tags: c, memset

This is giving me a segfault at the memset and I have no idea why, I am going to a specific index of a 2D array, this should give me a char pointer and allow me to use memeset.

```
void test(char** test)
{

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {

        memset(test[i],0,sizeof(char)*1);
        return;
    }
}

int main()
{

    char thing[20][20];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        memset(thing[i],0,sizeof(char)*20);
    }
    test(thing);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please see the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html).  An array is not a pointer.

Comment: Warnings are not for fun ! `expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[20]'`

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter declaration is incorrect, it should be:

```
void test(char test[20][20])
```

or:

```
void test(char test[][20])
```